# Raphael.js, problem with clear the canvas

Tags: javascript, raphael, javascript-framework

**myraphael.js:**

```
var raphael_test=function(){
  var canvas = Raphael("my-canvas", width, height);  

  return {
     startToDraw: function(){
        //canvas.clear() //Error happend when mouse click more than once
        canvas.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
     }
  };
}();
```

**draw.js**:

```
var btn=$('#btn');

btn.click(function(){

  raphael_test.startToDraw();
});
```

index.html:

```
<body>
    <div id="my-canvas"></div>
    <input type="button" id="btn"></input>

    <script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="myraphael.js"></script>
    <script src="draw.js"></script>
</body>
```

Every time when button clicked, I would like to first **clear** the previous draw, then draw the rectangular again.

I implement the **clear** part before `canvas.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);` **in myraphael.js**. But when mouse click on the button more than once, I got error from firebug: 
[image]

**raphael-min.js** is the Raphael library download from raphael official page.

I don't understand this error, and have no idea how to get rid of it...

Answer (score 0):

cavas != paper. this is a naming issue.

```
var width = 200;
var height = 200;

var raphael_test = (function() {

  var canvas = Raphael("my-canvas", width, height);  

  return {
     startToDraw: function() {
       canvas.clear(); 
       canvas.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
     }
  };
})();
```

btw: please make sure that all dom-objects are loaded properly and your js is wrapped by..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 ...
});
```

Comment: Hi, it is not a naming issue, it is just my typo. My code uses canvas. The problem is there even I do not have the typo.

Comment: have you checked if the dom-object with the id "my-canvas" is available? you could write console.log($("#my-canvas")); in the first line of raphael_test.

Comment: Mellon, i got your code running without any problems. http://jsbin.com/avera4/2/edit  (hope that helps)

Answer (score 0):

`canvas.clear()` is correct, but it is only accessible in `myraphael.js`. So, add a `clear` function to it:

```
var raphael_test=function(){
  var canvas = Raphael("my-canvas", width, height);  

  return {
     clear: function () {
        canvas.clear();
     },
     startToDraw: function () {
        canvas.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
     }
  };
}();
```

Comment: @Mellon, really need to see your updated code. Also you have an extra comma here: `<input type="button", id="btn"></input>`.

Comment: The code and error message is updated now in my post. There is no error when first click the button, error happens when click the button more than once.